# Ah, the old SE puzzlearoo

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

*Hold my crossword clues, I'm going in!*

> 1. 1973 Ford tow truck
> 2. Trip to geeks’ country in Portugal
> 3. Why Germany imprisons mother
> 4. John Stewart, according to Wikipedia
> 5. Classic m7xBI.jpg

Hello future solvers! Have you read the puzzle yet? If so, answer me this: **What am I thinking about right now?**

---

**HINT 1**: [No shovels, please!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/81382/57742)

**HINT 2**:

> Like the flavortext says, these aren’t crossword clues but something else entirely. Perhaps a more *direct search* is in order?

**HINT 3:**

> Each clue gives a specific thematic word, and the method to get each word is the same across all clues.

Comment: I think you spelled John wrong? Unless that's a clue.

Comment: @DonThousand No, it’s not misspelled, and I guess you can call it a clue, as long as you know the main mechanism

Comment: I haven't been on this site too long. Is there a puzzle I can look at to know what exactly this is?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can’t reveal the mechanism quite yet (in fact, that’s part of solving the puzzle in the first place!), but if you want to look at similar puzzles you can check out the enigmatic-puzzle tag :)

Comment: I get this reference

Comment: I feel like this is gonna end up being a rot13(ybpu arff zbafgre guerr svsgl wbxr)

Comment: @NickVitha - is that the one where, rot13(va 1998, Gur Haqregnxre guerj Znaxvaq bss Uryy Va N Pryy, cyhzzrgvat 16 sg guebhtu na naabhapre'f gnoyr?)

Comment: @MetaZen is it bad that I didn't even have to un-rot13 that to know exactly what it would be?

Comment: This has been a fun one.  I'm a bit stumped now after going down all the various rabbit holes.  Maybe another hint will help or someone will see a connection I'm not

Comment: @PilsNot3 - Please see my updated answer

Comment: Wrap it up, folks...

Comment: I like how you posted your hint separately to your puzzle. It makes the overall puzzle that bit more exciting! :)

Comment: @user477343 Thanks! The hint riddle was meant to be an alternative way of finding the gimmick, just in case the references in the flavortext were too oblique

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're thinking about:

> MEMES

The mechanism used:

> reddit uses an alpha-numeric pattern to code each comment/post.  Some of these randomly end up as "words".  By going to reddit.com/(whatever) you will go to a random post.  The clues are the random posts visited by using the names of subreddits as the code.  See here: https://www.reddit.com/r/NoStupidQuestions/comments/are009/why_does_redditcommusic_redirect_to_a_7_year_old/

1973 Ford tow truck

> http://www.reddit.com/music lands on a random post about the contents of this clue

Trip to geeks’ country in Portugal

> http://www.reddit.com/meirl lands on a random post about the contents of this clue  (Thanks to @noedne)

Why Germany imprisons mother

> http://www.reddit.com/iama lands on a random post about the contents of this clue

John Stewart, according to Wikipedia

> http://www.reddit.com/excel lands on a random post about the contents of this clue

Classic m7xBI.jpg

> http://www.reddit.com/texas lands on a random post about the contents of this clue

Now:

> By taking the first letter from the first answer, second from second, etc. we get Music mEirl iaMa excEl texaS, which spells out MEMES

Comment: Yep, that’s the mechanism! The rest might take a bit of finagling to find, but so far so good

Comment: Nice. Could #3 be this: https://www.reddit.com/r/reddit.com/comments/iama/germany_imprisons_mother_of_12_for_homeschooling/

Comment: Updated a couple answers.  I think I have #4 now

Comment: Updated my answer.  Thanks @noedne - that approach for the clue didn't occur to me.  Seems obvious now haha

Comment: Got it!  Actually, I almost just put that as the answer just because of the context without even seeing the pattern in the clues.  But thought it was too random with no reason for it.

Comment: Yes, that’s the final answer! If you can add explanations for all the parts of the puzzle, then I’ll accept this answer :)

Comment: Updated!  Nice puzzle!

Comment: I just tried clicking those links you gave (https://www.reddit.com/music etc) but they all gave me "Not Found". Huh?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is you are thinking about:

> this upcoming movie: GREEN LANTERN CORPS  (most clues point to this one)

Title: Ah, the old SE puzzlearoo

> This is clearly a reference to the "old redditaroo", in which a reddit post contains an ambiguous reference and a comment is made reacting to it as if the reference is pointing in the direction it clearly is not.  The comments are archived and daisy-chained together in a seemingly never-ending chain of fun.  People often declare "Hold my (whatever), I'm going in!" when reading the chain.  https://www.reddit.com/r/switcharoo/

1973 Ford tow truck

> This is a reference to the fact that when you visit reddit.com/music, you are redirected to a photo of a 1973 Ford tow truck.  You probably meant to visit reddit.com/r/music

Trip to geeks’ country in Portugal

> Found on dc site: Several years ago, the terrorist known as Kobra threatened to destroy Portugal's capital city Lisbon with a dangerous hydrocarbon weapon. The Justice League members Aquaman, Batman, and Green Lantern fought against Kobra, and though the villain escaped, they did succeed in saving Portugal.

Why Germany imprisons mother

> Doing a reddit search on this brings up several results, one of which references DC universe and Green Lantern Corps specifically: " Ever since the fateful day that Krypton was destroyed, the Green Lantern Corps has been preparing for the day that the legions of Apokolips might attack another inhabited world, and they have reason to believe that day is drawing near. "

John Stewart, according to Wikipedia

> John Stewart is one of the Green Lantern characters from DC

Classic m7xBI.jpg

> I found this referenced by a thread in the texas subreddit:  https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/texas/classic/

Still looking for better connections between some of these...

Comment: Any comment on whether any/all/none of my explanations of the clues are on the right track?  (Maybe which ones, specifically?)

Answer (score 1):

1. 1973 Ford tow truck

   > James Webster discovered that this seems to be an **F350**.
2. Trip to geeks’ country in Portugal

   > **Harry Potter** geeks might be interested to visit [the city of Porto](https://www.portugalist.com/harry-potter-porto/#Portuguese_Potter) in Portugal, where it's possible to go on [Harry Potter tourism](https://www.ecotoursportugal.com/en/travel-blog/porto-and-north-25/5-places-to-remember-harry-potter-639).
3. Why Germany imprisons mother

   > Following James Webster's idea, if this is letterplay it could be Y + DE + ? + MA. That doesn't give a word, but maybe an anagram of one?
4. John Stewart, according to Wikipedia

   > I've got nothing. [Too many to choose from!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Stewart)
5. Classic m7xBI.jpg

   > The [referenced image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pa4c.jpg) depicts a case of **irony**. Classical irony is one of the [types of irony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irony#Types).

Given [hexomino's confirmed answer to the hint puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/81440/5373), could it be that these five clues refer to

> subreddits?

Specifically,

> number 2 could be [r/HarryPotter](https://www.reddit.com/r/HarryPotter) or any of several others such as [r/RowlingWritings](https://www.reddit.com/r/RowlingWritings/), and number 5 could be [r/Irony](https://www.reddit.com/r/Irony/).

Comment: @PiIsNot3 No. 3 = [witchcraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katharina_Kepler)???

Answer (score 1):

Taking some from @Metazen

Partially done

1973 Ford tow truck

> music -> reddit.com/music (metazen) Looks right. redirects to /r/carporn

Trip to geeks’ country in Portugal

> tbd

Why Germany imprisons mother

> iama -> reddit.com/iama  (me), is right. redirects to /r/reddit.com

John Stewart, according to Wikipedia

> trees -> reddit.com/trees (metazen) I think this is wrong.

Classic m7xBI.jpg

> Texas -> reddit.com/texas (metazen) Is probably right. redirects to /r/funny

Some deduction, not an answer:

> These are all fairly big subreddits that are probably easily confusing people that don't put an r/ before the name.

Comment: @pilsnot3 I'm stuck from here. Am I on the right track?  For the Portugal one, I can't find anything.

Comment: Found #4, I think

Answer (score 0):

Flimsy reasoning so far but I think you're thinking about

> The Strange Case of Dr Jekyll and Mr Hyde

Pieces so far:

1. 1973 Ford tow truck

> The TV movie was released in 1973.
>  The most common result for a 1973 Ford Tow Truck is the F350. I don't know how this fits in.

2. Trip to geeks’ country in Portugal

*Nothing yet*

3. Why Germany imprisons mother

> Why = Y.
>  Germany = DE.
>  Imprisons = Hide
>  Mother = ?
>  Total = HYDE

4. John Stewart, according to Wikipedia

*Nothing yet*

5. Classic m7xBI.jpg

> The jpg on Imgur points to an image of an article condemning weedkiller called Atrazine with an ironic advert for Atrazine.
>  [image]
>  I think this might be a parallel to the Jekyll/Hyde conflict

Hint:

> Appears to point to Hunt for the Red October, a novel by Tom Clancy.
>  Resuming my flimsy reasoning: they're both novels.