# No shovels, please!

Tags: word, knowledge

> $ \color{red}E $
>   Second time skimming through
>   Beatles residence
>   Sandwich way

**What do these clues point to?** Looking for a single word answer.

---

<sub>*This puzzle is a hint for [Ah, the old SE puzzlearoo!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/81065/57742)*</sub>

Comment: In the interest of keeping this hint puzzle free of clutter, I will put any and all hints, rot13 of course, in the comments from now on

Comment: HINT 1: rot13(Gur svefg gjb yvarf pyhr gur jbeq vgfrys, gur ynfg gjb yvarf pyhr fbzrguvat eryngrq gb gung jbeq)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Building on previous answers, I think the answer may be

> Reddit

$ \color{red}E $

> Red E, italicized $\rightarrow$ Red E, it $\rightarrow$ Reddit

Second time skimming through

> "Read it" (past tense) sounds like Reddit.

Beatles residence

> As others have said, Yellow submarine $\rightarrow$ sub. 
>  A subreddit is a forum dedicated to a specific topic

Sandwich way

> As others have said, **Sub**way

Title

> The website Digg is a news aggregator with a curated front page and a competitor of Reddit.

Comment: Sounds convincing, but not sure I get the second line. Why "second time"?

Comment: @jafe the intention was that if you’ve skimming through something twice already, then you’ve already rot13(ernq vg)

Comment: @hexomino that’s the right answer! There’s a more cryptographic explanation for the first clue, but besides that it’s all correct

Answer (score 6):

Although it fits, this isn't the answer:

> I think this is an initial / acronym puzzle and the answer is:
>  RIDDLES

The Red E:

> Red Italic = RI

Second time skimming through

> Double Dip = DD

Beatles residence could be:

> "L" 
>  57 Green Street in London’s upscale Mayfair neighbourhood has the distinction of being the only home where all four Beatles lived at the same time – all crammed in together in “Flat L.” [ref](https://freetoursbyfoot.com/where-did-the-beatles-live-in-london/)
>  Although Liverpool or London both work just as well :)

Just thinking Sandwich Way could refer to :

> Earl (of Sandwich) and Street for way
>  giving ES

Comment: That’s a great answer, but unfortunately it’s not the right one, nor does it really give a hint for the linked puzzle. +1 for your efforts though!

Answer (score 2):

not actual answer, but some thoughts, it may help

> $ \color{red}E $ = red E = ready 
>  beatles residence may be London 
>  Sandwich way => sub*way* is a sandwich company. maybe we should combine *london* and *subway* to get *underground*.  
>  *beatles residence* could also be *yellow submarine* because *we all live in a yellow submarine*
>  as I said, not actual answer, I'm just writing down my thoughts, I may find later ;)

Answer (score 2):

Thoughts, similar to @Flying_whale but a few different things

> red-E = red-e (anagram of read) or potentially (wildly unrelated) something to do with red october?
>  second time skimming through = re-read?
>  beatles residence -> something to do with london, perhaps underground/tube or submarine for red october?
>  sandwich way, must be subway?

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be:

> Subreddit

Because

> Italicized Red E = Red E, It = Reddit

Second time skimming through

> Read it = Reddit

Beatles residence

> Submarine

Sandwich way

> Subway

This gives us:

> Sub

Which, added to the other answer, gives us

> subreddit, which is what reddit calls its sub-forums (like how stackexchange has all their different sites, like puzzling and roll playing etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but hexomino’s answer was the intended solution - read the hint I left in the comments for more info :)

Comment: To be fair, both fit your clues.

Comment: True, I probably should’ve made it clearer the separation between those clues, and either way they still give a hint to the main puzzle